# Are T-Bills "coupon equivalent" rates based in annual terms?

Tags: government-bonds, treasury

According to treasury.gov, the "coupon equivalent" for a 1 month (4 weeks) T-Bill issued today is 0.99%.

I happened to have purchased a 1 month T-Bill today for $99.9246. By my calculation that means that the return will be .075% (.0754/99.9246) for the month.  That leads me to believe that quoted coupon equivalent of 0.99% is actually annualized despite the fact that the T-Bill is only 1 month.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I hope you weren't expecting nearly a full 1% for one month?

Comment: Given that the 30 yr is below 3%, no. But I did think it was odd to annualize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annualizing offers a simpler way to compare 1 mo, 6 mo, and 1 yr treasuries. "Do I want to invest for 6 months to get 1%/yr or a year to get 1.1%?" That kind of choice.